# GCM - push notifications on chrome

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to understand how the GCM system works for chrome but the guides I find are mostly on android and ios while I want to use notifications for the web on a regular site. Like in any regular notification mode, I'd like to receive a notification on my browser when a variable changes and then I'd like to use the new value inside my script. 
I'm wondering if there is an event that I can listen to, something like onNotificationArrived() - in a javascript kind of way - that will let me handle the event and the payload/message in my browser and in my script

** EDIT: ADDED THE CODE ***

```
console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activated', event);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push Message', event);
  var data = event.data;
  console.log('data ',data);

  var title = data.title;
  console.log ('title ', title);
  var custom= data['custom'];
  console.log('custom ', custom);
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";  
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$apiKey = 'my_api_key';
$message = array(
    'message' => 'test message', 
    'title' => 'test title',
    'custom' => $myVar
);
$myVar = "34";

$registatoin_ids = array();
$selezione = "SELECT * FROM table";  
$update = mysqli_query($conn, $selezione);   
while ($row = $update->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($registatoin_ids, $row["gcm_id"]);
    echo($row["gcm_id"]);
}

$fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
         'data' => $message
     );


$test = json_encode($fields['data']);
echo($test);
$headers = array(   'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

//curl connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Where does the `variable changes` coming from? GCM is discussed in detail in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) (which also has a [GCM client for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client)). You'll receive a notification when the downstream message is called along with the `registration_token` it will be [sent to the Chrome App/Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm#event-onMessage) where you'll just have to implement the [notification](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications).

Comment: thank you for answering. I have a variable in a mysql database and I want to send notifications when this variable changes trough php. I've handled the registration of the token, and I get the notification, what I can't get is to pass the value of the variable in the notification so that I can take it and use it in the script. I thought the way was to edit the 'data' field inside the message but it doesn't seem to work (I've added the code to the question up here). When I run the script though, the javascript says that 'data' is null and there is nothing inside